# Textarea - missing new line

Tags: javascript, php, html, textarea, newline

I have following code:

```
<form action="../p/padd.php" method="POST"> 
<input type="button" value="Náhľad"  OnClick="javascript:nahlad()" /> 
<textarea tabindex="4" id="textra" name="text" ></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Vložiť" /> 
</form>

<span id="nahlad"> </span>

<script>
   function nahlad()
   {
     var textra = document.getElementById("textra").value;
     alert (textra);
     var xmlhttp;
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else
     {xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
   {
     document.getElementById('nahlad').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
   }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ssnahlad.php?text=" + textra,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

When I enter the following into the textarea (yes there is "new line" with enter)

```
asd
asd
```

and click the Nahlad button

ssnahlad.php contains

```
<?php
$new = $_GET['text'];
echo nl2br($new);
?>
```

so why does the span with id=nahlad contain

```
asdasd
```

instead of

```
asd
asd
```

Comment: You'll probably need to encode it before you send it with ajax. You could alert the value of textra before you send it and see what you get, probably "asdasd"

Comment: alert (textra); works right. there is not problem

Comment: contain the `$_GET['text'];` linebreak symbols `\r\n` or `\n` or something like that or contains only `asdasd`?? Try to use `var_dump()` for check that

Comment: string 'asdasd' (length=6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that I'm at home and can test, this will work:

```
  var newText = encodeURIComponent(textra);
```

using [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) before you send it will correctly render your output, with no decoding on the server side

Comment: What is you're reasoning behind doing this anyway?

Comment: i have textra where user enters text and i show him how it will look like on the page and i need to use new lines too and for some users it is hard to remember html codes to make new line ... that is just part of the code but there is mistake

Comment: Thanks, sorry it took a while; I hate trying to answer questions from my phone. Once I got home, it became pretty easy to fix.